# Bait and switch selling

Tags: canada, civil-law, consumer-protection

I purchased an 11-piece cabinet at a ridiculously low price and the order was confirmed by the corporate retailer. Few days after reviewing my order they have swapped out the item for a different item. Instead of the 11-piece cabinets it is now a vacuum on my order. I have all the supporting documents and pictures to prove it. Is this something I can go after the company for?

I am located in Canada and the product was purchase from a Canadian store

Comment: https://www.competitionbureau.gc.ca/eic/site/cb-bc.nsf/eng/00522.html#bait looks like a good place to start reading.  Especially the part about prices advertised in error, since that is probably what the company will claim happened.  It's not clear to me what the actual answer is, however.

Comment: What is your goal here? Are you trying to get your money back (which could be done by disputing the charges) or do you want to get more and/or stop them doing this?